# How to use MyBatis and Camel and Spring with annotations (interface Mapper)

Tags: spring, annotations, apache-camel, integration, mybatis

**How to use MyBatis with Camel flow with Spring(Boot) WITH annotations (intefrace)?**

It is working fine when I use Mybatis configuration in XML file.
Like:

```
<to uri="mybatis:selectSomething...">
```

(old fashion of springboot|camel)
with:

```
<mapper namespace="Something">
  <resultMap id="SomeObject" type="SomeObjectImpl">
    ...
  </resultMap>

  <select id="selectSomething" resultMap="SomeObject">
    SELECT something FROM somewhere WHERE id = #{id}
  </select>
...
```

Now I have:

```
public interface Mapper {
    @Select("SELECT something FROM somewhere WHERE id = #{id}")
    public List<String> selectSomething(@Param("id") int id); 
}
```

and it is working fine when I use it directly form java code.

But NOT working with camel flow

```
<to uri="mybatis:???...
```

There is no ID of select/statement which I can use.

Comment: You are incorrect. The XML approach is not 'old-fashioned' and is the only way to use the advanced features of MyBatis. The annotation approach is very limited and only works for simple DB interaction.

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported in camel-mybatis at this time of writing. But its a good idea to let us look into adding support for that. You are welcome to log a JIRA ticket at Apache Camel.